# Neo4j server failed to start :( It was working fine but suddenly it throwed error while starting.

Tags: neo4j

i just tried to access Neo4j through Gephi. After that when i tried to access Neo4j, it throw the following error. I'm using Neo4j 2.0.1.

Error:
    Starting Neo4j Server failed: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, C:\Users\Sakthi\Documents\Neo4j\default.graphdb

Comment: can you provide the full contents of your logfiles in `data/graph.db/messages.log` and `data/log/console.log` e.g. as a github gist

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure you don't have another Neo4j server running against the same folder
- Make sure the user running gephi has read/write access to that folder
- Look for the messages.log in that folder, and see if you can find any exceptions

Comment: Hi thanks for ur advice. I'll check the log file next time. Since i was having no time, i just uninstalled and reinsalled neo4j server once again.